# How do you call software that is not shareware but not totally free either?

Tags: payment, shareware

For example, Sublime Text 2. It's free but, time after time, not too often though, it pops up a dialog asking to purchase the bugging-free version. Is there a name for this type of software distribution model.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this type of software is called "Nagware" because it nags you to pay money.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagware.